# How to Move EntityFramework DataModel to separate folder in Same project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I'd like to move EDMX file with all of its dependencies (tt,vb, autogenerated classes from db) to avoid mess in Project root directory. Just move it to DataModel Directory.

[image: Move edmx to directory in project]

When I did it, refreshed model and so on everything looks fine. I didnt get any errors from ctontext.tt template. But when I run the application and pass first EF DB call, I got:

> MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

I tried to change webconfig connection string from

```
<add name="TransparencyMSD" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BLAHDataModel.csdl..." />
```

to

```
<add name="TransparencyMSD" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel/BLAHDataModel.csdl..." />
```

But, no luck :(

I know that I forgot about something, would somebody will be so kind and at least point me where to look?

I searched in SO for possible solution, but nobody had the same scenario.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to add the directory name to the paths in the connection string, but separated by a dot:

```
<add name="TransparencyMSD" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.BLAHDataModel.csdl" />
```

Comment: Thank you for following through with it -- had the same problem and this helped fix it!

Comment: @taiji123 - no problem, it was solved when I created another project with desired structure. Coincidence ;)